# How can I show the same product multiple times in the shopping cart?

Tags: cart

I don't want to set a min qty, customers should be able to buy many of the same product. But I would like to make it explicitly clear they have added more than qty=1 to their cart.

I've unsuccessfully dug around into enough nooks of the Mage core to believe this is anything trivial. But maybe it is? Anyone have an idea how I might approach this..

Thanks, Kev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `custom options` for this.

***Steps:***

1. Log into admin panel and go to Catalog > Manage Products
2. Select the product which you want to show multiple times in the cart
3. In the left panel select `Custom Options` tab
4. Add a custom option

e.g.

[image]

1. Now the product detail page will be as follows.
   [image]
2. If you add the same product with different values for this custom field, each product will be added to the cart as a new entry. See the image below.
   [image]

> Note: To add the same product as a new entry to the cart, at least one
>   single difference should be among those products. (Otherwise quote
>   always check the newly added product with the parent product.) So by
>   using custom options you can achieve this.

Comment: Its working fine. One question here. How can I add value for the custom option programmatically?

Comment: Ask a different question, So I can explain it there. Hard to provide sample code in comments

Answer (score 5):

You could make each item unique by adding a custom product option (just some random number, time added to cart, ...) to differentiate it. This will list them individually since it will run into compareOptions in

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php

```
public function representProduct($product)
{
    $itemProduct = $this->getProduct();
    if (!$product || $itemProduct->getId() != $product->getId()) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check maybe product is planned to be a child of some quote item - in this case we limit search
     * only within same parent item
     */
    $stickWithinParent = $product->getStickWithinParent();
    if ($stickWithinParent) {
        if ($this->getParentItem() !== $stickWithinParent) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Check options
    $itemOptions    = $this->getOptionsByCode();
    $productOptions = $product->getCustomOptions();

    if(!$this->compareOptions($itemOptions, $productOptions)){
        return false;
    }
    if(!$this->compareOptions($productOptions, $itemOptions)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4745/9) has some info on how you could use a product option.

Comment: ahhh! Crafty solution, brother! I'll give this a shot